# Put request with headers not working

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a list of dictionary as

```
list = [{'a':1,'b':2},{'c':3,'d':4}]
```

I need this list to be sent through python `requests.put` method. I tried to put

```
headers = {'Content-Type':'Application/json'}
requests.put(url, data=list, headers = headers)
```

but it says too-many arguments to unpack.
This put request is successful through google's RestClient setting content-type to 'application/json'.

How can set header for put request?

Comment: i did not understand the question - seems like you are saying that it is working. so where is the problem?

Comment: Please provide the full script if possible. I have tested letter for letter, using my own url and do not get the same issue. Whats the actual error thrown to console?

Comment: Probably, list must be dumped to json string, i.e. data=json.dumps(list)

Comment: data = json.dumps(list) did solve my problem. Thanks for the response